# Query Mongodb on month, day, year... of a datetime

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm using mongodb and I store datetime in my database in this way

for a date "17-11-2011 18:00" I store:

```
date = datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 17, 18, 0)
db.mydatabase.mycollection.insert({"date" : date})
```

I would like to do a request like that

```
month = 11
db.mydatabase.mycollection.find({"date.month" : month})
```

or

```
day = 17
db.mydatabase.mycollection.find({"date.day" : day})
```

anyone knows how to do this query?

Comment: My approach got some performance problems, use only if you have no other choice ( refer my post and comments). Instead DrColossos answer is a best way to do that...   please accept his as answer

Comment: This clearly is not a duplicate. If the way the syntax was described in this question was actually to be implemented in MongoDB some day, we would never find it in the answers to the other question, as they ask for two entirely different things (comparing date properties vs. finding within timespan). The solutions happen to be the same, but they do not have to, and could theoretically (and maybe *will* some day) vary.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Dates are stored in their timestamp format. If you want everything that belongs to a specific month, query for the start and the end of the month.

```
var start = new Date(2010, 11, 1);
var end = new Date(2010, 11, 30);

db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
//taken from http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/
```

Comment: Is it the only way? Is there any possibility to only retrieve the month of my date object in my database?

Comment: @DrColossos, there is a another way to do this using $where

Comment: @DrColossos, seems your approach is better than mine.. $where expression has got some performance problems, pls check my answer for more info...

Comment: you need to plus one day to the `end` to make sure all 31 days are included. Btw, `month=11` is December, not November. The Op seems to refer to Nov.

Comment: it doesn't work when filtering by a specific day. ie: birthdates.

Comment: Wow, does this suck or what...if you want to query by specific day, you have to be careful about the days and the end of the month....month can have 28,29, 30 or 31 days...why couldn't they make something like: date: { $year: 2014, $month:4 }? This isn't a query language, but programming.

Comment: @dakt you are right there is a problem with this answer. it does not show results for the last day of the month and when month has more than 30 days. check my answer!

Comment: @dakt In mongodb we have now Date Aggregation Operators, by which we can search like date: { $year: 2014, $month:4 }, check my answer below

Comment: @DrColossos in your specific example, shouldnt this be `end = new Date(2010, 12, 01)`?

Answer (score 34):

You cannot straightly query mongodb collections by date components like day or month. But its possible by using the special **$where** javascript expression

```
db.mydatabase.mycollection.find({$where : function() { return this.date.getMonth() == 11} })
```

or simply

```
db.mydatabase.mycollection.find({$where : 'return this.date.getMonth() == 11'})
```

(But i prefer the first one)

Check out the below shell commands to get the parts of date

```
>date = ISODate("2011-09-25T10:12:34Z")
> date.getYear()
111
> date.getMonth()
8
> date.getdate()
25
```

**EDIT:**

Use $where only if you have no other choice. It comes with the performance problems. Please check out the below comments by @kamaradclimber and @dcrosta. I will let this post open so the other folks get the facts about it.

and check out the link [$where Clauses and Functions in Queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-%7B%7B$where%7D%7DClausesandFunctionsinQueries) for more info

Comment: this is a convenient idea, however the use of $where is really discouraged if you want to have good performance : it takes a global lock. See @DrColossos answer for a better way to do this.

Comment: @kamaradclimber, yeah thats true, i am aware that this is slower than the native operators, since no indexes used. But i am not sure about the global lock.. are you sure..? any links that confirms the claim very helpful....

Comment: I've not found any trace of lock in the docs. Here is a link for performance loss : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-%7B%7B%24where%7D%7DClausesandFunctionsinQueries. I think I got the lock idea from the db.eval paragraph so let's just forget it :-)

Comment: The answer from DrColossos is still much much faster

Comment: It's not a lock, per se, but each `mongod` instance only has one javascript context in which to execute any javascript (`$where`, map-reduce jobs, etc). Queries will yield periodically, so one query won't fully block another, but multiple queries or other javascript work will be slower. This is why `$where` is not recommended.

Comment: @dcrosta, thanks for the clarification..   i ll let this answer open, so other folks will know the facts.  and i ll ask OP to accept the DrColossos answer...

Comment: @RameshVel ,  I have try above answer but it gives me the MongoError: $where not allowed in this atlas tier,
how can I solve this error

Answer (score 13):

how about storing the month in its own property since you need to query for it?  less elegant than `$where`, but likely to perform better since it can be indexed.

Comment: Much better, this is the right way to do (AKA index ^^).

Answer (score 13):

Use the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator which allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language. This will give you the power to use the [Date Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-operators) in your query as follows:

```
month = 11
db.mydatabase.mycollection.find({ 
    "$expr": { 
        "$eq": [ { "$month": "$date" }, month ] 
    } 
})
```

or

```
day = 17
db.mydatabase.mycollection.find({ 
    "$expr": { 
        "$eq": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }, day ] 
    } 
})
```

---

You could also run an aggregate operation with the [`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) function that takes in a [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline:

```
month = 11
db.mydatabase.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ { "$month": "$date" }, month ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

**For the other request**

```
day = 17
db.mydatabase.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }, day ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

---

### Using OR

```
month = 11
day = 17
db.mydatabase.mycollection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$or": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ { "$month": "$date" }, month ] },
                        { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }, day ] }
                    ] 
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

---

### Using AND

```
var month = 11,
    day = 17;
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$and": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ { "$month": "$createdAt" }, month ] },
                        { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfMonth": "$createdAt" }, day ] }
                    ] 
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

The **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** operator incorporates the functionality of **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** and **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline and  will return all documents match the condition using **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** and discard from the pipeline those that don't match using the **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** variable.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to search for documents that belong to a specific month, make sure to query like this:

```
// Anything greater than this month and less than the next month
db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: new Date(2015, 6, 1), $lt: new Date(2015, 7, 1)}});
```

Avoid quering like below as much as possible.

```
// This may not find document with date as the last date of the month
db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: new Date(2015, 6, 1), $lt: new Date(2015, 6, 30)}});

// don't do this too
db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: new Date(2015, 6, 1), $lte: new Date(2015, 6, 30)}});
```

Comment: Great principle in general. Date searches should almost always have an inclusive start date and an exclusive end date.

Answer (score 7):

You can find record by month, day, year etc of dates by **Date Aggregation Operators**, like **$dayOfYear, $dayOfWeek, $month, $year** etc.

As an example if you want all the orders which are created in April 2016 you can use below query.

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project:
         {
           doc: "$$ROOT",
           year: { $year: "$created" },
           month: { $month: "$created" },
           day: { $dayOfMonth: "$created" }
         }
     },
     { $match : { "month" : 4, "year": 2016 } }
   ]
)
```

Here created is a date type field in documents, and $$ROOT we used to pass all other field to project in next stage, and give us all the detail of documents.

You can optimize above query as per your need, it is just to give an example. To know more about Date Aggregation Operators, visit [the link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/).

Comment: and if I wanted to do a random one-month year and day how it would look

Comment: @Punnet Singh, Sir I want data by month depent on createdAt how can fixed it ?
I send month value from Postman

Answer (score -1):

You can use [MongoDB_DataObject](https://github.com/viettranme/MongoDB_DataObject) wrapper to perform such query like below:

```
$model = new MongoDB_DataObject('orders');

$model->whereAdd('MONTH(created) = 4 AND YEAR(created) = 2016');

$model->find();

while ($model->fetch()) {
    var_dump($model);
}
```

OR, similarly, using direct query string:

```
$model = new MongoDB_DataObject();

$model->query('SELECT * FROM orders WHERE MONTH(created) = 4 AND YEAR(created) = 2016');

while ($model->fetch()) {
    var_dump($model);
}
```