# Querying date in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I m trying to query my collection by a range of date. I m trying to use ISODate in the query passing a javascript date and it doesn't work, and I dont know why...

I have tried :

```
db.collection.aggregate {date: {$gt: 'new Date(' + start.toISOString() + ')', $lt: 'new Date(' + end.toISOString() + ')'}}, {"$group": {_id: "$user", count: {$sum: 1}}}

db.collection.aggregate {date: {$gt: 'ISODate(' + start.toISOString() + ')', $lt: 'ISODate(' + end.toISOString() + ')'}}, {"$group": {_id: "$user", count: {$sum: 1}}}

db.collection.aggregate {date: {$gt: 'ISODate(' + start + ')', $lt: 'ISODate(' + end + ')'}}, {"$group": {_id: "$user", count: {$sum: 1}}}

db.collection.aggregate {date: {$gt:start, $lt: end}}, {"$group": {_id: "$user", count: {$sum: 1}}}
```

Nothing works...

Can you help me ? Or explain me why it doesn't work in each case ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB/Mongoose querying at a specific date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973304/mongodb-mongoose-querying-at-a-specific-date)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put `Date` constructors as strings and concatenate it with `start`, `end` values? Comparing `Date` objects to strings like `"new Date(2014-10-20T15:27:24.110Z)"` is not gonna work for sure.

If `start`, `end` are plain JavaScript `Date` objects, you can construct the `ISODate` objects for comparison using the `ISODate` helper like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {date: {
        $gt: ISODate(start.toISOString()),
        $lt: ISODate(end.toISOString())
    }}},
    {$group: {_id: "$user", count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

Comment: Start and end are javascript dates. I ll try tomorrow thank you