# Mongoose Update Condition PDT Date/ Model ISO Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi my Schmema has a field with an ISO-Date:

```
ISODate("2015-04-30T14:47:46.501Z")
```

Paypal returns on a successful payment a date object in that form:

```
Time/Date stamp generated by PayPal, in the following format: HH:MM:SS Mmm DD, YYYY PDT
Length: 28 characters
```

Now I want to update the database entry which has the payers_email_address and a timestamp which does maximum differ from paypals timestamp by 15min.

These are the steps I think are necessary to do this:

1) On this step I'm not sure. The blunt way would be to Stringify the paypal date and then to split it and rearrange it. But I guess there is a better way?

**Question:** How to convert the PDT date properly into the UTC date.

2) Make a new UTC date:
var dt = new Date('2010-06-09T15:20:00Z');

3)
Add 15 min to the date:
dt.setMinutes (dt.getMinutes() + 15);

4) Query inbetween two dates
[MongoDB/Mongoose querying at a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973304/mongodb-mongoose-querying-at-a-specific-date)

In whole (does not work for a date on 30/04/2015)

```
MyModel.find({date: {"$gte": new Date("10:00:46 04 29, 2015").toUTCString(), "$lt": new Date("14:00:46 05 01, 2015").toUTCString()}})
```

EDIT:

I guess if I got the query bove working I can just use the same with PDT:

```
new Date("20:15:10 05 10, 1985 PDT").toUTCString()
```

I posted my steps because maybe there is mongoose function for converting the date and I don't have to do 1-3.

Answer (score 1):

This works in my mongoShell I will report later if it worked in the program:

```
MyModel.find({date: {"$gte": new Date("10:00:46 04 29, 2015 PDT"), "$lt": new Date("14:00:46 05 01, 2015 PDT")}})
```