# Get a query with string mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5713af5e39dd161a0c546501"),
    "year" : "1949",
    "_created_at" : ISODate("2016-04-17T15:44:30.221Z"),
    "_updated_at" : ISODate("2016-04-17T15:44:30.221Z"),
    "date" : "10.1" // 10 is day 1 is the month
```

I have my collection called `quotes` with the structure above.

In the express app I want to get all the data for each month. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
mongoose.model('quotes').find({ date: { $search : id  } },function (err, quotes) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    } else {
      //respond to both HTML and JSON. JSON responses require 'Accept: application/json;' in the Request Header
      res.send(quotes);
    }
});
```

`id` here is the month; like, if it is `1` that means it is January. I get no response back when executing the code.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB/Mongoose querying at a specific date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973304/mongodb-mongoose-querying-at-a-specific-date)

Comment: in this example it is a date object but i have a string date

Comment: `"date" : "10.1"` it is a `string`

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I thought you were querying the `_created_at`. Misread it

Comment: Try this:   mongoose.model('quotes').find({ "day" : new RegExp("^"+ id + ".*", "i") },function (err, quotes) {