# mongodb find query if the time difference between current date and createdAt date is less than 60 minutes

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hi Guys I am trying to write a complex query in mongodb to fetch documents where date time difference between current server date and createdAt date is less 60 minutes.

Mongoldb -v 3.0.10
currentDate = new Date();
db.blog.find({'blogStatus':'OPEN'})

want to apply something like this:

if currentDate.getMinutes() > 60 minutes true show document false don't show document

Comment: this is duplicate. Just go with $gte or $lte (grater/lesser than) paremeter in query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB/Mongoose querying at a specific date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973304/mongodb-mongoose-querying-at-a-specific-date)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get posts that are newer than 60 minutes old, then you need to include something like this in your query:

```
db.blog.find({
  blogStatus: 'OPEN',
  createdAt: {
    $gt: date,
  }
});
```

where `date` is a date calculated by subtracting 60 minutes from the current time. If you use something like [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) then you can use this to subtract minutes:

```
moment().subtract(60, 'minutes');
```

Make sure you get the format and timezone right for Mongo. This should work:

```
var date = moment().subtract(60, 'minutes').utc().format();
```

Without Moment and inside the Mongo shell, such a date can be constructed with something like:

```
var date = new Date(new Date() - 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you @rsp. db.blog.find({'blogStatus':'OPEN','createdAt':{'$gte':date}})

Answer (score 0):

I finally used below query
db.blog.find({'blogStatus':'OPEN','createdAt':{'$gte':date}})