# time slot query in mongoose (mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose

I am new to mongoose.I am trouble in storing time slots in mongoose db.
I have to store time slot for example - 10:00 to 14:00,where startingTime is 10:00 and endTime is 14:00.

So each time when I query the documents in between these time slots of any day.I should get those documents that has these time slots.

I want to make query that do comparison on time slots not on datetime parameter.

I am getting whether I have to store them as string or date ?

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB/Mongoose querying at a specific date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973304/mongodb-mongoose-querying-at-a-specific-date)

Answer (score 0):

There is no type in Mongo that is a time slot. You need to store two values yourself and compare with them in searches. Far example if you have `start` and `end` fields then you may search with:

```
Model.find({start: {$lte: now}, end: {$gte: now}}, ...);
```

to find something that is happening now, where `now` is the current time.

Comment: so we cannot do comparison in time slots like 10:00 > 09:00?