# find mongodb collection document with date String

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have date string like

> 2022-05-17

And My mongodb collection document like

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "aabbccddeeff" },
  "title": "test",
  "content": "test",
  "author": "tester",
  "churchId": { "$oid": "e5eakjshuwb3546" },
  "markAsRead": false,
  "createdAt": { "$date": "2022-05-17T08:18:57.174Z" },
  "updatedAt": { "$date": "2022-05-17T08:18:57.174Z" },
  "__v": 0
}
```

Now How do I find this collection using date string like mention above.

I have used this query as well

```
.find({ churchId, createdAt: new Date(createdAt) }, ' -__v')
```

But couldn't work.

Comment: The same  question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973304/mongodb-mongoose-querying-at-a-specific-date

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
createdAt: {$gte: ISODate("2022-05-17T00:00:00"), $lte: ISODate("2022-05-17T23:59:59")}
```

It will bring all the docs falls on the given day.

Comment: Thanks Gibbs.. I have fixed using your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If project environment like typescript ,then `ISODate` shows an error like:

> 'cannot find ISODate'

So we can use `new Date()` class like:

```
createdAt: {
  $gte: new Date("2022-05-17T00:00:00"),
  $lte: new Date("2022-05-17T23:59:59")
}
```