# How can I query for all documents that were created at a specific time each day?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm clear on how to query documents within a range, but if I want, say, all docs in a collection created at 3PM (assuming I have a field with that stored of course -  lets call it `createdAt`), what would that query look like?  At present these dates are stored in my collection as JavasSript Date objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB/Mongoose querying at a specific date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973304/mongodb-mongoose-querying-at-a-specific-date)

Comment: Check out the [date expression operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators) such as `$hour`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$hour": "$createdAt"
          },
          15
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PdJatoDaQWK)