# Mongodb - which data type for events

Tags: mongodb, non-relational-database, nosql

I am a Mongo DB beginner.

I have to create a collection that can store events. All the documents in the Event will  have a FROM_TIME and TO_TIME keys whose values can vary as follows :

1. {FROM_TIME : "September 1,1939", TO_TIME : "August 1945"}
2. {FROM_TIME : "August 15,1947", TO_TIME : "August 15,1947"}
3. {FROM_TIME : "1857", TO_TIME : "1858"}
4. {FROM_TIME : "December 7,1944 11:00", TO_TIME : "December 7,1944 14:40"}
5. {FROM_TIME : "January 1971", TO_TIME : "November 1972"}

Given the random occurrence of the FROM_TIME and TO_TIME, will it be possible to query for events like :

1. List of events in the second half of the 19th century
2. List of events on August 15
   and so on.

I request people here to provide leads in case I need to rethink the structure of my collection as I'm quite naive at Mongo(or any other non-relational)DB.

*****1st Edit begins here

I wrote the following code:

```
DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();

        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_ID", new ObjectId());
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_DESC", "Pearl Harbour");
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_FROM_TIME", Date.valueOf("1944-12-07"));
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_TO_TIME", Date.valueOf("1944-12-07"));
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_EVNTCMPD_ID", new ObjectId());
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_MTRL_ID", null);
        // dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_AUDIT", 1);
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_REMARKS", "First insert");

        eventAtomic.insert(dbObject);
dbObject = new BasicDBObject();

        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_ID", new ObjectId());
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_DESC", "1857 Revolt");
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_FROM_TIME", "1857");
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_TO_TIME", "1858");
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_EVNTCMPD_ID", new ObjectId());
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_MTRL_ID", null);
        // dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_AUDIT", 1);
        dbObject.put("EVNTATMC_REMARKS", "Only years");

        eventAtomic.insert(dbObject);
```

Here, I dumbly used String to store incomplete dates but how should I store just an year like 1992, 2001, 2012 or just a month like January, September or something like August 2010 ? I'm not sure as to whether I'm expecting the correct thing ! Please guide me as to how I must handle such 'incomplete' timings.

*****1st Edit ends here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the FROM_TIME and TO_TIME as DateTime. See Here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates

Then, you can query (rang query for example)
see the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8136834/131809

So, for all events on August 15th 2012:

```
var start = new Date(2012, 08, 15);
var end = new Date(2012, 08, 16);

db.myEventCollection.find({created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

Comment: Hi alexjamesbrown,
I had read that Date doc. before posting the question and I'm not sure if that data type will allow to store only year, only month and year, only month or such type of 'incomplete' date data; also the thread that you have provided says 'You cannot straightly query mongodb collections by date components like day or month'.
Please guide.

Comment: You can't directly query by "month" but you can query for range... so, to query by month, as per my example, you could query for greater than 1st Jan 2012 and less than 1st Feb 2012

Comment: I have edited my question - added a code snippet demonstrating my exact query. Please do have a look and guide me.

Comment: Since you used strings, there's nothing you can do other than == "1857" Probably best to dump your data and start again.

Comment: I used String as I couldn't figure out any other way to store the incomplete time. Please tell me whether it is possible or not so that I can think of alternatives.

Comment: It's not possible - you can't do < "1999" for example... it's a string. You could possibly cast to int, but that would be extremely inefficient. Your best bet is to re-import the data. Or, write a script to convert your string fields to datetime or int