# How to find/query dates by year in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Given some sample collection data:

```
{
    "question" : "Which do you usually eat?",
    "pubDate" : ISODate("1999-01-24T13:00:00Z"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("51d7f9e231d2fe0000000002"),
}
{
    "question" : "Which language do you usually speak?",
    "pubDate" : ISODate("2013-12-02T13:00:00Z"),
    "_id" : ObjectId("51d8a476a6b9d70000000006"),
}
```

How would you query for all questions from 1999? What I'm after is something like:

```
db.poll.find({pubDate.year: 1999})
```

I've found that I can take the following [date range query approach](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/), but it seems like there should be a simpler way:

```
db.poll.find({
  pubDate: { 
    $gte: new Date("1 Jan, 1999"), 
    $lt: new Date("1 Jan, 2000")
  }
});
```

Comment: This is currently the most index efficient method, the one through AF below will not use the index effectively

Comment: Sorry, what does 'AF' mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query Mongodb on month, day, year... of a datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136652/query-mongodb-on-month-day-year-of-a-datetime)

Comment: Sorry about that I meant aggregation framework

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you could denormalize your schema a bit, by storing along with "pubDate" some "pubDateObj" with separate fields like 'year', 'month' etc. and create index by pubDateObj.year.
You should design your schema in a way to best fit to your application's queries.