# Query Mongodb on specific or range month without year of a datetime

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongodb to store datetime.

**example**

DB data:

```
[
{
  id: 1
  date: '2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z'
},
{
  id: 2
  date: '2013-10-11T00:00:00.000Z'
},
{
  id: 3
  date: '2012-11-21T00:00:00.000Z'
}
]
```

filter by month 11, like query.find({'date': {$month: 11}}) should get result:

```
[
{
  id: 1
  date: '2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z'
},
{
  id: 3
  date: '2012-11-21T00:00:00.000Z'
}
]
```

How to do that query to get what I want?

I search and got [Query Mongodb on month, day, year... of a datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136652/query-mongodb-on-month-day-year-of-a-datetime), but it's not that I want, I don't want to filter the year of date.

Comment: Are your `date` values strings (like you show) or BSON Dates?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, BSON Date, I edited it. thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`$month`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month) is an aggregation operator, so it can only be used with `aggregate`, not `find`:

```javascript
db.test.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        id: 1,
        date: 1,
        month: {$month: '$date'}
    }},
    {$match: {month: 11}},
    {$project: {
        id: 1,
        date: 1
    }}
])
```

Result:

```javascript
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5453d0b73712b66352662484"),
            "id" : 1,
            "date" : ISODate("2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5453d0b73712b66352662486"),
            "id" : 3,
            "date" : ISODate("2012-11-21T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: great, but your way need to know what's the name of all fields. Have the way to do that if I don't know fields name?

Comment: Sort of, you can put `doc: $$ROOT` in your initial `$project` instead of the individual fields.

Comment: This could take ages if I have 5 milion records to $project. The match should be a first step.