# How could I fitler array by time period(HHMM~HHMM) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I got the flights by mongoid.

How could I quick filter the flights by `departure_at` between `time interval (HHMM)`

For example,

When the time interval is a string `06:00~09:00`

The result should be

```
[2] #<Jetstar _id: 20150720_0655_1040_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-20 06:55:00 UTC
[5] #<Jetstar _id: 20150722_0655_1040_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-22 06:55:00 UTC
[7] #<Jetstar _id: 20150723_0655_1040_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-23 06:55:00 UTC
```

When the time interval is a string `10:00~18:00`

The result should be

```
[1] #<Jetstar _id: 20150719_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-19 12:45:00 UTC
[3] #<Jetstar _id: 20150720_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-20 12:45:00 UTC
[4] #<Jetstar _id: 20150721_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-21 12:45:00 UTC
[6] #<Jetstar _id: 20150722_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-22 12:45:00 UTC
[8] #<Jetstar _id: 20150723_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-23 12:45:00 UTC
[9] #<Jetstar _id: 20150724_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-24 12:45:00 UTC
```

## whole datesets

```
[1] #<Jetstar _id: 20150719_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-19 12:45:00 UTC
[2] #<Jetstar _id: 20150720_0655_1040_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-20 06:55:00 UTC
[3] #<Jetstar _id: 20150720_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-20 12:45:00 UTC
[4] #<Jetstar _id: 20150721_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-21 12:45:00 UTC
[5] #<Jetstar _id: 20150722_0655_1040_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-22 06:55:00 UTC
[6] #<Jetstar _id: 20150722_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-22 12:45:00 UTC
[7] #<Jetstar _id: 20150723_0655_1040_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-23 06:55:00 UTC
[8] #<Jetstar _id: 20150723_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-23 12:45:00 UTC
[9] #<Jetstar _id: 20150724_1245_1630_TPE_KIX|OSA, departure_at: 2015-07-24 12:45:00 UTC
```

Comment: What types of things have you tried? What exactly are you stuck with? Can you show us the code you have tried?

Comment: i'm just planing how to write the kind of code to cherry pick the time interval i want. like `morning flight 06:00~09:00`

Answer (score 1):

In mongoid you can use between to do a search of records within a range. I don't recommend that you do the filtering directly in Ruby as this will be slow and memory intensive for larger data set.

This post goes through a solution:

[Query Mongodb on month, day, year... of a datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136652/query-mongodb-on-month-day-year-of-a-datetime)

However, if you want to do it in pure ruby you could do:

```
start, finish = "06:00~09:00".split('~')
start_hour = start.split(':')[0].to_i
end_hour = finish.split(':')[0].to_i

flights.select do |flight|
  flight.departure_time.hour >= start_hour && flight.departure_time.hour <= end_hour
end
```

This will just query for hours. You can include minutes by doing:

```
start, finish = "06:00~09:00".split('~')
start = start.split(':').map(&:to_i)
finish = finish.split(':').map(&:to_i)

# Work in minutes
start_minutes = start[0] * 60 + start[1]
finish_minutes = finish[0] * 60 + finish[1]

flights.select do |flight|
  dep_mins = flight.departure_time.hour * 60 + flight.departure_time.min
  dep_mins >= start_minutes && dep_mins <= finish_minutes
end
```

Comment: no, i think do it in ruby is quite quick than in mongoid. because i only need fetch whole data from database rather than access DB multiple times. i don't think mongo can filter the condition, by morning, by night :)

Comment: OK I'll update my solution to show a pure ruby way :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `datesets` is an array of `Jetstar` objects:

```
require 'time'

def date_filter(datesets, min, max)
  datesets.select { |d| Time.parse(d.departure_at).hour.between?(min, max) }
end

# 06:00~09:00 inclusive
p(date_filter(datesets, 6, 9))

# 10:00~18:00 inclusive
p(date_filter(datesets, 10, 18))
```