# Fetching Data from MongoDB according createdAt column only with date

Tags: mongodb

I have collection Ticket_master,which like as follows

**Ticket_master**

```
{
   _id:5e70ed53de0f7507d4da8dc2,
   "TICKET_NO" : 1000,
   "SUBJECT" : "Sub1",
   "DESCRIPTION" : "Desc1",
   "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-17T15:31:31.039Z"),
}
```

Already  tried with the following code snippet and it returns null result set.

```
db.getCollection('ticket_masters').find({ 'createdAt':ISODate('2020-03-17T00:00:00.000Z')})
```

How fetch fetch data from ticket_master collection by matching the value with date of creation column,which is represented as `createdAt`.

Following code snippets return the results. Because it contain both date and time.How fetch data from the collection only with Date .

```
db.getCollection('ticket_masters').find({ 'createdAt':ISODate('2020-03-17T15:31:31.039+00:00')})
```

Comment: Possible duplicated from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136652/query-mongodb-on-month-day-year-of-a-datetime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query Mongodb on month, day, year... of a datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136652/query-mongodb-on-month-day-year-of-a-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as you are searching for all the tickets that have been created on some day, so you can use a date range to filter the tickets

```
db.getCollection('ticket_masters').find({ 
    createdAt : { 
        $gte: ISODate('2020-03-17T00:00:00.000Z'), 
        $lt: ISODate('2020-03-18T00:00:00.000Z') 
    } 
})
```

this should return all the tickets that have been created on 17/03/2020

check this [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LadCROgmWCX)